# java: annotation processor + code generation

Tags: java, performance, annotations, code-generation, annotation-processing

the following problem:

```
class Testcontroller
{
    @endpoint
    @roleAdmin
    public void test1(Request req)
    {

    }

    @endpoint
    @roleModerator
    public void test2(Request req)
    {

    }
}
```

**after processing, this should be the result:**

```
class Testcontroller
{

    public void handleRequest(Request req)
    {
        switch (req.endpoint)
        {
            case "test1":
                if (req.role.hasAdmin()) this.test1(req);
                break;
            case "test2":
                if (req.role.hasModerator()) this.test2(req);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void test1(Request req)
    {

    }

    public void test2(Request req)
    {

    }

}
```

The problem here is, that java annotation processor cant replace existing source/classes, but can only gernate new once. Ok there is a solution out there, which can modify existing code, but its a hacky solution and i guess not the elegant way.

So what can i do?
Maybe my annotation processor creates a new class TestcontrollerIntern, which get my switch-case block with that role-checks. it would delegate the requests to methods of the origin Testcontroller-methods. But so i have there un-necassary delegations between objects.

**And how get my programm be informed about that new gernerated (proxy-)classes?
I guess i have to do it manual? or i have to use there again reflection?**

what i can do else?
i can copy my whole codebase to a tmp-folder, parse my annotations and replace in that tmp-folder the java-source-data-files as my code-example suggests. After that, i compile my project (in the tmp-folder) and remove that tmp-folder then.

*(so i dont use the annotation processor.
maybe - i dont know - is that the better way, cause the annotation-processor isnt the best way, getting optimized code? -> here im not sure...)*

**so im looking for the best solution.
how would you solve that?**

Comment: But the factory needs to know which concrete class it have to instanciate, it must know about the generated classes?! (i guess that can be done with reflection, or i have to code that dependency hardcoded into my code, and have to update each time i get new generated classes). So there i have only a single-point (the factory) where i have adjust the whole thing, but i have to do it - or have to use reflection. The question: is that acceptable way. or is there a better one? What kind of technique use the pros? Springboot or something like that?

Comment: maybe to generate first all java-sources and compile then (i mentioned in the secound part in my question) is way which is more performant? But is it also the  more sensible way? I dont know, so that question here....^^

Comment: My idea with that copying of that files is the following: copy them to a tmp location, replace there the annotated classes through the new "classes", compile that all, remove the tmp folder... why you think, that isnt a good idea?
I read about that subMavenModuls. But you mean with the generated sources i get there, i get .class files no java files, right?

Comment: the thing with the reflection: i hope that the reflection is only then overhead, then i calculate it, right? But if i calculated the pointer/memory-adress of the destination, then it is as performant as i wouldnt use reflection?
reflection -> calculate pointer to Class#forName(String) -> save that pointer and reuse it. My problem there is, that i calculate that pointer at run-time and not at compile time. If the compiler would calculate that pointer, then he could do some optimiziations. If i do this over reflection, i dont get that optimiziations. So i guess ....

Comment: ... always i use reflection, it is a little bit slower, not only then i calculate the pointer, but also after that.... of course java makes then run-time optimiziations, but the compile-time optimizations are still missing. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes that i meant. But the question here: is that really 100% the same as i would instanciate it with the new keyword?. Cause if i instanciate that with the new-keyword, the compiler see that, and could do therefore a few optimiziation, which would of course missing if i do it over reflection. But maybe there arent optimizations by the compiler, So in that case it would be really more or less 100% the same. I dont know so much about that specific compiler optimiziations, so i ask

Comment: _Annotation processing is not meant for replacing classes_
in my case i wouldnt use a classic annotation processing. Here i would use a code generator, which reads the annotation at runtime. It would be a simulated class replacement^^ No hack. Still copying the original files to a tmp folder. then i star my specific program which replace the java-classes. After that i would start the compiler, which see human-readable javafiles, who compiles them. No hack or special trick. So why isnt that a good solution?

Comment: Yes. Reflection is _always_ slower than not using reflection. But sometimes reflection is the only way, or at least easiest way, to implement something. In this specific case, the _only place_ reflection is used is during instantiation—afterwards, code using the instance doesn't use reflection. And again, avoid premature optimization. You're talking about saving microseconds which is inconsequential, unless you're _really, really, **really**_ sure you _absolutely must_ improve the performance _of this one specific part of the code_. Don't waste resources. Write code that works and is readable.

Comment: Also, the Java compiler does very little in the way of optimizations. Virtually all optimizations come from the _just-in-time_ (JIT) compiler—at runtime. And I suppose you're talking about runtime generation of classes (e.g. using the Java Compiler API). That's not necessary a bad idea, though I don't see how that avoids reflection. It can also be done in-memory (unless you want to avoid generating the classes each time the application is executed).

Comment: No i dont meant that. I have there more rounds: i start the application. Then i read the annotations WITH reflection-> so now i can let my special application generate human-readable-java-files, which should replace in my tmp folder the original human-readable-java-files (that one, which have the annotations). So now  my special program is exited. Now i compile all sources in the tmp-folder. The output is saved. the tmp-folder is destroyed. If i now execute the ouput (for example a jar-file) then i dont have any more reflections there.

Comment: _Don't waste resources. Write code that works and is readable_
i guess you are right there. I am often too perfectionistic - unnecessarily